# "Figures' description" vs. "Description of Figures"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality

I need to use a sentence as a title. which one is better?

> Figures' description

Or

> Description of Figures

Comment: Could you provide more context please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While both are grammatically correct as phrases (not complete sentences), "Description of Figures" will be better understood as a title.